# iPhone gaming: How to animate spaceship explosion?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If one ship is moving toward another and fires on it, how do I animate that explosion while having the firing ship keep moving?   Using something such as cocos2d in a 2D game.  Any online references are appreciated.

Also, does anyone have a reference to the crashlanding game that use to be on the Apple developer site?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [this open-source particle-system](http://code.google.com/p/iphoneparticles/) for the iPhone.
The original author has some posts about it on his [blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/particle-generator-bugfixes.html).

> how do I animate that explosion while having the firing ship keep moving?

If you are using the default OpenGL ES Xcode template, you should already have seperated draw/update loops. So you could update the particle system within `-(void)updateView` and remove the ship from your scene data structure after the explosion is over.

> Also, does anyone have a reference to the crashlanding game that use to be on the Apple developer site?

Apple pulled it because the audio code was no longer usable after iPhone OS 2.1